# Authorize nested and polymorphic resources (cancan)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, ruby-on-rails-3.2, cancan

Have models User, Project, Document, Issue, Comment, Ability:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :projects
end

class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_and_belongs_to_many :users
  has_many :documents
end

class Issues < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Document < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :project
  has_many :comments, :as => :commentable
end

class Comment < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :commentable, :polymorphic => true
end

class Ability
  include CanCan::Ability

  def initialize(user)
    user ||= User.current

    can :read, Project, :id => user.project_ids
    can :manage, Document, :project => { :id => user.project_ids }
  end
end
```

Routes:

```
resources :projects, :shallow => true, :path => '/', :only => :show do
  resources :documents do
    resources :comments
  end
  resources :issues do
    resources :comments
  end
end
```

Controllers:

```
class DocumentsController < InheritedResources::Base
  load_and_authorize_resource :project
  load_and_authorize_resource :document, :through => :project, :shallow => true

  # GET /1/documents
  # GET /1/documents.json
  def index
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @documents = @project.documents.page(params[:page])

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @documents }
    end
  end

  # POST /1/documents/new
  # POST /1/documents/new.json
  def new
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @document = @project.documents.build

    respond_to do |format|
      format.html
      format.json { render :json => @document }
    end
  end

  # POST /1/documents
  # POST /1/documents.json
  def create
    @project = Project.find(params[:project_id])
    @document = @project.documents.build(params[:document])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @document.save
        format.html { redirect_to @document, notice: 'Document was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render json: @document, status: :created, location: @document }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @document.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Abilities for project is ok, but creating document fails.
Questions:

1. What I do wrong for Document abilities?
2. How can I write abilities for comments (polymorphic and nested)?

Answer (score 0):

For creating Document

Add "can :create, Document " in ability class because at the time create action is called 'project' is nil for that Document.

Writing ability for comment:

Can you explain what you want to achieve ? If you want to users to read others users comment then

Add few relation in user model :

has_many :documents, :through => :projects

has_many :comments,  :through => :documents

Then in you ability class add

can :read, Comment, :commentable_id => user.comment_ids

Answer (score 0):

InheritedResources need to add belongs_to param:

```
belongs_to :project, :optional => true
```

Find more @ https://github.com/ryanb/cancan/wiki/Inherited-Resources